# Get the number of appearances of a particular term in an elasticsearch field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an elasticsearch index (posts) with following mappings:

```
{
    "id": "integer",
    "title": "text",
    "description": "text"
}
```

I want to simply find the number of occurrences of a **particular term** inside the description field for a **single particular document** (i have the document id and term to find).

e.g i have a post like this {id: 123, title:"some title", description: "my city is LA, this post description has two occurrences of word city "}.

I have the the document id/ post id for this post, just want to find how many times word "city" appears in the description for this particular post. (result should be 2 in this case)

Cant seem to find the way for this search, i don't want the occurrences across ALL the documents but just for a single document and inside its' one field. Please suggest a query for this. Thanks

Elasticsearch Version: 7.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `terms` aggregation on your `description` but need to make sure its `fielddata` is set to `true` on it.

```
PUT kamboh/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "simple_analyzer": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true,
            "analyzer": "simple"
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ingesting a sample doc:

```
PUT kamboh/_doc/1
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "some title",
  "description": "my city is LA, this post description has two occurrences of word city "
}
```

Aggregating:

```
GET kamboh/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "terms_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "description.simple_analyzer",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yielding:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "terms_agg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "city",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "description",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now, as you can see, the [`simple` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) split the string into words and made them lowercase but it also got rid of the duplicate city in your string! I could not come up with an analyzer that'd keep the duplicates... With that being said,

### It's advisable to do these word counts before you index!

You would split your string by whitespace and index them as an array of words instead of a long string.

---

This is also possible at search time, albeit it's very expensive, does not scale well and you need to have `script.painless.regex.enabled: true` in your es.yaml:

```
GET kamboh/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "terms_script": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "params": {
          "word_of_interest": ""
        },
        "init_script": "state.map = [:];",
        "map_script": """
              if (!doc.containsKey('description')) return;

              def split_by_whitespace = / /.split(doc['description.keyword'].value);

              for (def word : split_by_whitespace) {  
                 if (params['word_of_interest'] !== "" && params['word_of_interest'] != word) {
                   return;
                 } 

                 if (state.map.containsKey(word)) {
                   state.map[word] += 1;
                   return;
                 }

                 state.map[word] = 1;
              }
""",
        "combine_script": "return state.map;",
        "reduce_script": "return states;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
...
"aggregations" : {
    "terms_script" : {
      "value" : [
        {
          "occurrences" : 1,
          "post" : 1,
          "city" : 2,  <------
          "LA," : 1,
          "of" : 1,
          "this" : 1,
          "description" : 1,
          "is" : 1,
          "has" : 1,
          "my" : 1,
          "two" : 1,
          "word" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
...
```